# B-1/B-2 visa vs J-1 visa

Tags: b1-b2-visas, j1-visas

My friend and I got a training offer from a company in the US. They sent us an invitation letter and my friend had her interview last week and got rejected because she requested a B-1/B-2 visa. The interviewer claimed that she should have requested a J-1 visa instead but the company hasn't sent any additional papers other than the invitation letter. I'm sure I've read that B-1 visa can include a short term training in case it was unpaid and not promising any employment for the future (which is our case) also J-1 visa , as I understood, requires a "sponsor" and I'm not sure if every institution can be considered as a certified sponsor. I also requested a B-1/B-2 visa and my interview is in two days so I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2):

well there might be a problem of perception here, with you and your employer, you don’t specify how long the training last, maybe that’s why the company be concerned, also what is about the training course maybe the company maybe had problems in the past concerning that.

My advice call the company and ask about what kind of visa you will need, if they need you to have a j1 visa they should be able to sponsor you.